# Syntax error in Create Table Statement MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Im not that familiar with MS Access SQL commands. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my create statement below?

Create Table Extract(  [WeekID] TEXT(10) , [RetailerID] INT  , [ItemCode] INT  , [SaleType] TEXT(1)  , [Multiple] INT   , [Store] INT  , [DateCollected] DATETIME  , [Price] DECIMAL(9,4) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main problems with this statement.

Firstly, `Extract` is a [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845663.aspx#sectionSection3) in Access SQL. That means you have to surround it by `[]` brackets.

Secondly, the `DECIMAL` data type is only supported in Access SQL when executing SQL in ANSI mode. You can see how to switch your database to ANSI mode in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382850/7296893), or you can execute your query using the following line in the immediate window:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "Create Table [Extract]( [WeekID] TEXT(10) , [RetailerID] INT , [ItemCode] INT , [SaleType] TEXT(1) , [Multiple] INT , [Store] INT , [DateCollected] DATETIME , [Price] DECIMAL(9,4) )"
```

Furthermore, I recommend using `NVARCHAR` over `TEXT` in queries. There's no functional difference as long as you specify a field size smaller than 255, but `TEXT` usually refers to the *Long Text* data type, a harder to work with data type that can take very long strings.