# Derived Tables vs Queries and Updating Data

Tags: sql, ms-access, derived-table

We use software connected to a database that has certain requirements for records in the table *assay*, however, our database is larger than just what this software uses and stores all data relating to assays in the table *sample*.

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `sample_id` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  `depth_from` real,
  `depth_to` real,
  `hole_id` varchars,
  `bag_id` varchar(255),
  `type` varchar(255),
  `weight` real,
);
```

Samples of *sample.type* 'rock chip' have a *sample.depth_from* value while samples of *sample.type* 'crm' do not. The software uses the subset 'rock chip' to display a downhole log. i.e. I need to use a subset of table *sample*.

```
SELECT *
FROM sample
WHERE sample.type="rock chip"
;
```

Too much detail?

Here is the issue; since .accdb was introduced I cannot connect directly to a query, I assume because of the updated data types. The software was originally designed to do this because this is a very common kind of dataset. So, aside from being very annoyed, I am also trying to use derived tables to get around this. But, how do I write back to the original table? With a query, changes and new records would be written to the *sample* table. I see *assay* as a temporary thing so changes can't go there. I see problems arising.

Also, the new table query has to be run manually and that is definitely going to be an issue. Users can't be messing with queries.

```
SELECT * INTO assay
FROM sample
WHERE sample.type="rock chip"
;
```

How would you go about making a table temporarily and making sure it can be written back to the original table? Is there a way to make this happen automatically?

And in MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a view:

```
CREATE VIEW assay AS
    SELECT *
    FROM sample
    WHERE sample.type = "rock chip";
```

This is evaluated when the user uses the view.  So, it is always up-to-date.

Comment: "The Microsoft Access database engine does not support the use of CREATE VIEW, or any of the DDL statements, with non-Microsoft Access database engine databases."

Comment: The only things that I might guess is the semicolon at the end.  However, this needs to be done directly in the database:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-view-statement-microsoft-access-sql.  Although presumably you are using MS Access as the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382064/ensure-sql-92-on-access-2000-mdb-to-sql-server-under-access-2010

Comment: It just creates a query. Sigh. Not going to work

Comment: I don't get the point of CREATE VIEW if it just creates a query.

Comment: @Elizabeth . . . It created a *named* query that looks like a table.  It is not "just a query".

Comment: I am unsure of the difference. It literally puts the SELECT query into a query with the name I gave it. And it is exactly like any other query I have created.